# Theoretical minimal number of blocks in group - ext2

Tags: filesystems, ext3

I have a theoretical question. I don't know if it is proper place for it, but I think that you can help me :)

If minimal number of busy blocks in each group is always > 3 ?

Honestly, I have no idea. I know structure of group:

[image]

Super block, DataBlock Bitmap, Inode Bitmap are neccessary. So in each group at least 3 blocks are busy.   What about Group Descriptors ?  Is it neccessary for each group ?